# provide a mask to pandas dataframe as function argument

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use a mask as a function argument. What works:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[50, 100, 1], [0, 2, 1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

# the function argument
kwargs = {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c':1}

# generate a list of the elements
temp = []
for item in kwargs.items():
    temp.append('(data.{}'.format(item[0]) + ' == {})'.format(item[1]))
temp

# generate mask as string
mask = ' & '.join(elem for elem in temp)

# apply mask
data[eval(mask)]
```

I was wondering if

a) there is a more elegant solution ?

b) does the `èval(mask)` potentially cause troubles if the size of the dataframe gets larger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
data[pd.DataFrame(data[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items()).all()]
```

Using a generator comprehension, it creates a DataFrame of `bool`s for whether or not the `data` value is equivalent to the `kwargs` value. It calls `.all()` on this dataframe, and uses that as the mask.

`eval` is strongly discouraged for use in most code - there is almost always a better solution. For example, `eval(mask)` will cause issues if the column is not accessible via `data.column_name` (if the name is not valid, such as `x y`).